# 'err: insufficient funds for gas * price + value:

Tags: web3js, transactions, sendtransaction, sendsignedtransaction, sepolia

I am using sepolia testnet, to make a signed transaction between two accounts locally, below is the code :---

```
let { Transaction: Tx }= require('ethereumjs-tx');
let {Web3} = require('web3');

const account1 = '0x2832B429C73f74Fd6B4612ff0b6c97801fd18553';
const account2 = '0x6a7e74b23019F03B2E287cb241eE520F875C7443';

const privatekey1 = Buffer.from('c0********************************************76','hex')
const privatekey2 = Buffer.from('8a********************************************30','hex')

const privateKey1Uint8Array = new Uint8Array(privatekey1);
const privateKey2Uint8Array = new Uint8Array(privatekey2);

const url = 'https://rpc-sepolia.rockx.com'

let web3 = new Web3(url);

web3.eth.getBalance(account1)
  .then((bal) => {
    const balance = web3.utils.fromWei(bal, 'ether');
    console.log('Balance:', balance);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error:', err);
  });

web3.eth
  .getTransactionCount(account1)
  .then((txCount) => {
 
    // Build the transaction
    let txObject = {
      nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
      from: account1,
      to: account2,
      value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.1', 'ether')),
      gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei')),
      chainId: 11155111
    
    };

    

    // Sign the transaction
    const tx = new Tx(txObject);
    tx.sign(privateKey1Uint8Array)
    const rawArray = tx.raw
  

    const serielizedtransaction = tx.serialize();
    const raw = '0x' + serielizedtransaction.toString('hex');
    
    // BroadCast the transaction
    web3.eth
      .sendSignedTransaction(raw)
      .then((txHash) => {
        console.log("Transaction Hash", txHash);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error:", err);
      });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Error:", err);
  });
```

The output:---

```
Balance: 0.399968499999769
Error: TransactionRevertInstructionError: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM
    at /home/runner/Check2/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/utils/get_transaction_error.js:48:21
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/runner/Check2/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/utils/get_transaction_error.js:24:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/home/runner/Check2/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/utils/get_transaction_error.js:20:12)
    at getTransactionError (/home/runner/Check2/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/utils/get_transaction_error.js:33:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Check2/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/rpc_method_wrappers.js:439:100)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/runner/Check2/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/rpc_method_wrappers.js:21:58) {
  innerError: undefined,
  reason: 'err: insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address 0x2832B429C73f74Fd6B4612ff0b6c97801fd18553 have 399968499999769000 want 4284899617421126307357911857367734556889520 (supplied gas 21000)',
  signature: undefined,
  receipt: undefined,
  data: undefined,
  code: 402
}
```

I mean how it's possible that transaction requires '4284899617421126307357911857367734556889520 wei'  which is '4284899617421126307357911.85736773455688952 eth' for execution? been stuck in this error for 2 days, any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the instructions as per [infura docs](https://docs.infura.io/tutorials/ethereum/send-a-transaction/use-web3.js) on web3.js now its working

POV :- The code asked in question in 4-5 years old, many things have been changed as per new documentation. Please refer to that, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know,you can try:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");

const providerRPC = {
  development: "http://127.0.0.1:8545/",
  moonbase: "",
};
const web3 = new Web3(providerRPC.development); // Change to correct network

const account_from = {
  privateKey:
    "0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80",
  address: "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266",
};
const addressTo = "0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8";

const balances = async () => {
  // 4. Fetch balance info
  const balanceFrom = web3.utils.fromWei(
    await web3.eth.getBalance(account_from.address),
    "ether"
  );
  const balanceTo = web3.utils.fromWei(
    await web3.eth.getBalance(addressTo),
    "ether"
  );

  console.log(`The balance of ${account_from.address} is: ${balanceFrom} ETH`);
  console.log(`The balance of ${addressTo} is: ${balanceTo} ETH`);
};
const send = async () => {
  console.log("Transaction Start:");
  console.log(
    `Attempting to send transaction from ${account_from.address} to ${addressTo}`
  );

  const createTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
    {
      to: addressTo,
      value: web3.utils.toWei("10", "ether"),
      gas: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei("10", "gwei")),
    },
    account_from.privateKey
  );

  const createReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
    createTransaction.rawTransaction
  );
  console.log(
    `Transaction successful with hash: ${createReceipt.transactionHash}`
  );
  console.log("Transaction End!");
};
async function main() {
  await balances();
  await send();
  await balances();
}
main();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i think you are using Ganache local environment, would like to mention that , when I run my mentioned code using Ganache, it works fine but when I try this using the Ethereum testnet like Sepolia or Goerli it shows the error(in question), Any explanation about this will really help, thanks!